# Can't install sasl package in Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, ubuntu, hive, pip, sasl

I want to install pyHive package in ubuntu. Using this step:-

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
pip install sasl
pip install thrift
pip install thrift-sasl
pip install PyHive
```

but when i install sasl package it's given me error

```
Using cached sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/shivam_gupta/Documents/pip3-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sasl) (1.14.0)
Installing collected packages: sasl
    Running setup.py install for sasl ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/shivam_gupta/Documents/pip3-venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vokx0cvb/sasl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vokx0cvb/sasl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hqi5nw58/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/shivam_gupta/Documents/pip3-venv/include/site/python3.7/sasl
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vokx0cvb/sasl/
    Complete output (32 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
    copying sasl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
    running egg_info
    writing sasl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to sasl.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
    running build_ext
    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
    gcc -pthread -B /home/shivam_gupta/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isasl -I/home/shivam_gupta/Documents/pip3-venv/include -I/home/shivam_gupta/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl/saslwrapper.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:254:0:
    sasl/saslwrapper.h: In member function ‘void saslwrapper::ClientImpl::interact(sasl_interact_t*)’:
    sasl/saslwrapper.h:437:11: warning: unused variable ‘input’ [-Wunused-variable]
         char* input;
               ^~~~~
    g++ -pthread -shared -B /home/shivam_gupta/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/shivam_gupta/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/shivam_gupta/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl/saslwrapper.o -lsasl2 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl/saslwrapper.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    unable to execute 'g++': No such file or directory
    error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/shivam_gupta/Documents/pip3-venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vokx0cvb/sasl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vokx0cvb/sasl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hqi5nw58/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/shivam_gupta/Documents/pip3-venv/include/site/python3.7/sasl Check the logs for full command output.
```

My python version:- 3.7.6

What I do for installing hive in my ubuntu system?
And thrift-sasl also not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> unable to execute 'g++': No such file or directory

You don't have GNU C++ compiler. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```